# Can I roll back to a previous OS version on the iphone 5?

Tags: ios

I updated my phone from OS 8.4 to 9.2. I don't like how my phone lags now and the battery lasts way less then it used. Can you guys please help if there is a way I can go back to OS 8.4?

Comment: Short answer, no. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 8.4, no. iOS 9.1, yes. The reason your iPhone is lagging so much is because iOS 9.2 is beta software. iOS 9.1 is the latest public release of iOS 9 and is what you should downgrade to. Apple has instructions on their website on how to accomplish this.